# How to add Pagination in Dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

I am new to flutter. I want to know that is there anyway that i can apply pagination to the dropdown list in flutter?

it's a dummy data.

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get dropdownItems{
 List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [
  DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("USA"),value: "USA"),
  DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Canada"),value: "Canada"),
  DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Brazil"),value: "Brazil"),
  DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("England"),value: "England"),
  ];
 return menuItems;
  }
class _DropdownItemState extends State<DropdownItem> {
  String selectedValue = "USA";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return DropdownButton(
    value: selectedValue,
    items: dropdownItems
  );
 }
}
```

now if i have a lot of data coming from api, so how can i apply pagination to that in dropdown list in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You can use `infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.1.0` for pagination  and here is the link [Here is the link](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination)

Comment: I want to know that how can I apply pagination to dropdown list?

Comment: @Bunny Did we get any way to achieve paginated list view for Drop down selection?